# SQL COUNT GROUP BY multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

I have 10 + tables that all have a column 'Error Message'. There is a unique ID for each Error Message. I need to write a script that returns the top 5 most recurring errors between all tables. Here is an example of the current structure along with the desired result.

Tables

```
Table 1
**Error Message        
     Mes 1              
     Mes 2                
     Mes 3                    

Table 2
**Error Message     
     Mes 1
     Mes 2            
     Mes 3               
     Mes 4
     Mes 4 
     Mes 4 
     Mes 4                       

Table 3
**Error Message                         
     Mes 5
     Mes 1                 
     Mes 6
     Mes 2
```

Desired Result

```
**Error Message      Error Count**     
     Mes 4                4
     Mes 1                3
     Mes 2                3
     Mes 3                2
     Mes 5                1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select errMsg, count(*) as errCnt
from
(
    select errMsg from table1
    union all 
    select errMsg from table2
    union all 
    select errMsg from table3
    ...
) tmp
group by errMsg
order by count(*) desc
```

Depending on your DB engine add either `limit 5` or `top 5` or `ROWNUM <= 5`